# CasperJS click is leads to error even when the element exists

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, click, casperjs

I'm trying to click on a logout button, which I have retrieved from the current page. I successfully got the `id` of the logout link. But when I click on it, an error occurs

> Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector

```
function getLogoutId()
{
    var logoutid = "";
    $(document).find("a").each(function(key,value){

        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        if(id.toLowerCase().indexOf("logout") > -1)
        {
            __utils__.echo("insidelogout" + id);
            logoutid = id;
        }
    });

    return logoutid;
}


var logoutid = this.evaluate(getLogoutId);
fs.write("logout.txt", this.getHTML(), 'w');
this.thenClick("#"+logoutid, function(){});
```

I have written the html content to a file, in which I checked for the `id` and it is there. The `id` attribute in question looks like this:

```
et-ef-content-ftf-flowHeader-logoutAction
```

Comment: the id contains dashes `et-ef-content-ftf-flowHeader-logoutAction`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just `this.click("#"+logoutid);`?
Also have you considered using jQuery to click on the button? Something like this...(first make a variable of your id so you can pass into jQuery).

```
var id = "#"+logoutid;
this.evaluate(function(id){
      jQuery(id).click();
},id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your code aside from strange usage of jQuery.

You can try other CSS selectors for clicking:

```
casper.thenClick("[id*='logout']"); // anywhere
```

or

```
casper.thenClick("[id$='logoutAction']"); // ending
```

or

```
casper.thenClick("[id|='logoutAction']"); // dash-separated
```

Maybe it is an issue with the code that follows the shown code. You can try to change `thenClick` to `click`.